# Flink datastream - process data from file using windows

Tags: flink-streaming

I'm learning Flink framework and working on a streaming job that will read data from a csv file and perform some aggregation using the DataStream API. The data fields include  city, state code, population values. Data will be keyed by state code and the sum of population of each key calculated. The output will be in that format: (state code, sum of population).

My current implementation uses a reduce function on the KeyedStream to aggregate the population. This gives me a rolling reduce for each key. I'm looking to only print the last sum for each key. My undesrtanding is that the data will need to be windowed in order to emit the last result per window. I'm unsure how to implement a window assigner that will account for all the data within the file. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

(side note: I came accross event-time processing in the Flink documentation. If the csv can be updated to add a last_update file, could that be used as window for the purpose of accountig for all data in the file)

Answer (score 0):

A streaming reduce has to produce an updated result after processing each incoming record, because each record could turn out to be the last -- there's no way of knowing when the stream might end.

But if your input is actually bounded (as it is in this case of reading from a file), then you can run your streaming job in BATCH execution mode, and the reduce will only produce a final result -- no need for windowing.

A couple of quick examples showing how to run in BATCH mode:

```sh
$ bin/flink run -Dexecution.runtime-mode=BATCH examples/streaming/WordCount.jar
```

```java
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);
```

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/execution_mode/